# mysql can't use locks with log tables

Tags: mysql, debian

When I run `mysqlcheck` command in Debian MySQL 5.1, I get the below messages:

```
Debian:~# mysqlcheck --all-databases -u root -p

Enter password:
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log
Error    : You can't use locks with log tables.
status   : OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slow_log
Error    : You can't use locks with log tables.
status   : OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
```

I want to know how to fix the error messages of the `You can't use locks with log tables`.

Comment: are you trying upgrade mysql or u did upgrade it already?

Comment: I am not upgrading mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running table checks implicitly locks the table (equivelant to executing 'LOCK TABLES') to prevent concurrency issues. The log engine is a table type (just like myisam and innodb) that was introduced in 5.1 which do not need - and thus do not support - locking. The slow log and general log use said engine by default.
The message you are seeing is harmless. The issue you linked too says users can ignore the misleading message, and that the message will be removed in a future version.

For reference:

Bug reported on this issue

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30487

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43829